# Is memory out respond for linux system hanging on?

Tags: linux, memory, server

my machine is using Gentoo system, today it hang on again, except powering off and restarting, I couldn't do anything. After checking /var/log/messages, I think the reason is running out of memory, is it right? I also check demesg, and think it is in normal situation. What log should I check? Any suggestion would be grateful!

Following is information may lead to system hang on (at 10:30, I power off and restart the machine):

```
Mar 24 01:38:34 pluto postfix/postdrop[62292]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/728405.62292: No such file or directory
Mar 24 01:38:34 pluto postfix/postdrop[68665]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/728406.68665: No such file or directory
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: samtools invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x200d2, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: samtools cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: CPU: 75 PID: 78085 Comm: samtools Not tainted 4.1.15-gentoo-r1 #1
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Hardware name: Inspur NF8460M4/NF8460M4, BIOS NF8460M4_1.2.5 03/22/2016
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  0000000000000000 ffff8801a43a7a98 ffffffff815ef069 0000000000000007
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  ffff883e87560290 ffff8801a43a7b48 ffffffff81149b46 0000000000000020
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  0000000000000003 0000000000000100 0000000000745d1b ffff883e87560290
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff815ef069>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff81149b46>] dump_header.isra.11+0x76/0x210
Mar 24 01:38:37 pluto postfix/postdrop[141845]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/446518.141845: No such file or directory
Mar 24 01:38:38 pluto postfix/postdrop[54616]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/24737.54616: No such file or directory
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff812a67e4>] ? ___ratelimit+0x84/0x110
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff8114a3e0>] oom_kill_process+0x330/0x390
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff810623ae>] ? has_capability_noaudit+0x1e/0x30
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff8114a738>] __out_of_memory+0x2f8/0x330
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff8114a92b>] out_of_memory+0x5b/0x80
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff8114f36d>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x89d/0x970
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff811a9fc9>] pipe_write+0x219/0x450
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff811a1411>] __vfs_write+0xb1/0xf0
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff811a1c49>] vfs_write+0xa9/0x1b0
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff811a2986>] SyS_write+0x46/0xc0
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel:  [<ffffffff815f4b5b>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x6e
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Mem-Info:
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: active_anon:130956673 inactive_anon:2642 isolated_anon:0\x0a active_file:6214 inactive_file:6760 isolated_file:260\x0a unevictable:10983 dirty:7115 writeback:1635 unstable:0\x0a slab_reclaimable:53541 slab_unreclaimable:39821\x0a mapped:438
1 shmem:210563 pagetables:267076 bounce:0\x0a free:493478 free_pcp:238 free_cma:0
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: DMA free:14856kB min:0kB low:0kB high:0kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0
kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1847 515106 515106
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: DMA32 free:1891572kB min:232kB low:288kB high:348kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1972224kB managed:1894608kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writebac
k:0kB mapped:8kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 513258 513258
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Normal free:67484kB min:65296kB low:81620kB high:97944kB active_anon:523826692kB inactive_anon:10568kB active_file:24856kB inactive_file:27040kB unevictable:43932kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):1296kB present:534773760kB managed:525576
696kB mlocked:43936kB dirty:28460kB writeback:6540kB mapped:17516kB shmem:842252kB slab_reclaimable:214164kB slab_unreclaimable:159284kB kernel_stack:28592kB pagetables:1068304kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:868kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_s
canned:1352 all_unreclaimable? no
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: DMA: 2*4kB (U) 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 14856kB
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: DMA32: 5*4kB (UM) 8*8kB (UM) 8*16kB (UM) 5*32kB (UM) 4*64kB (UM) 3*128kB (M) 5*256kB (UM) 4*512kB (UM) 5*1024kB (UM) 1*2048kB (U) 459*4096kB (MR) = 1891572kB
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Normal: 16388*4kB (UEM) 45*8kB (UEM) 4*16kB (M) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB (R) = 70072kB
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: 226411 total pagecache pages
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: 134190493 pages RAM
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: 2318691 pages reserved
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: 0 pages hwpoisoned
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 3294]     0  3294     8038     1096      18       3        0         -1000 udevd
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4348]    60  4348   311292    28625     116       4        0             0 mysqld
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4416]     0  4416     8507      149      18       3        0             0 syslog-ng
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4417]     0  4417   877038     1370      92       6        0             0 syslog-ng
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4445]     0  4445    32489     4280      30       3        0             0 glusterd
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4530]     0  4530   200648   151741     358       4        0             0 glusterfs
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4539]     0  4539   355462     8491     414       4        0             0 glusterfsd
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4543]     0  4543    56402     7962      44       3        0             0 glusterfs
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4576]     0  4576     6996      428      17       3        0         -1000 sshd
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4605]     0  4605    59610     4019      92       3        0             0 apache2
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4639]     0  4639     4423      480      14       3        0             0 crond
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4666] 65534  4666    52450      808      48       3        0             0 gmetad
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4698] 65534  4698    31317      830      31       3        0             0 gmond
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4722]     0  4722    29745      826      26       4        0             0 trqauthd
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4749]     0  4749  2636348    22424     314      13        0             0 pbs_server
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4812]     0  4812    18660    10985      41       3        0         -1000 pbs_mom
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4838]     0  4838     4304      418      13       3        0             0 agetty
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [ 4839]     0  4839     4304      420      13       3        0             0 agetty
```

some information were omit here

```
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [84860]  1601 84860   361540    22187      96       5        0             0 LAcheck
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [84865]  1601 84865     2410      372       9       3        0             0 bash
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [84866]  1601 84866   361540    22161      96       4        0             0 LAcheck
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: [84867]  1601 84867    13830     2105      31       3        0             0 python2.7
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 84352 (daligner) score 36 or sacrifice child
Mar 24 07:44:58 pluto kernel: Killed process 84352 (daligner) total-vm:19494908kB, anon-rss:19469220kB, file-rss:1712kB
Mar 24 01:39:39 pluto postfix/postdrop[71340]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/326461.71340: No such file or directory
Mar 24 01:39:39 pluto postfix/postdrop[28818]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/744675.28818: No such file or directory
Mar 24 01:39:39 pluto postfix/postdrop[58585]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/744864.58585: No such file or directory
Mar 24 01:39:39 pluto postfix/postdrop[141845]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/745005.141845: No such file or directory
```

I power off machine and restart at 10:30:

```
Mar 24 01:44:40 pluto postfix/postdrop[68665]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/950329.68665: No such file or directory
Mar 24 01:44:40 pluto postfix/postdrop[62292]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/950322.62292: No such file or directory
Mar 24 01:44:41 pluto postfix/postdrop[55494]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/150142.55494: No such file or directory
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@Mar 24 10:39:53 pluto syslog-ng[4461]: syslog-ng starting up; version='3.7.2'
Mar 24 10:39:56 pluto kernel: igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: igb: enp4s0f0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
Mar 24 10:39:56 pluto kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0f0: link becomes ready
Mar 24 10:39:56 pluto sshd[4620]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 24 10:39:56 pluto sshd[4620]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 24 10:40:00 pluto crond[4683]: (CRON) STARTUP (1.5.0)
Mar 24 10:40:00 pluto crond[4683]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 67% if used.)
Mar 24 10:40:00 pluto crond[4683]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Mar 24 10:40:00 pluto /usr/sbin/gmetad[4710]: data_thread() for [BGM] failed to contact node 127.0.0.1
Mar 24 10:40:00 pluto /usr/sbin/gmetad[4710]: data_thread() got no answer from any [BGM] datasource
Mar 24 10:40:00 pluto PBS_Server[4794]: LOG_ERROR::Operation now in progress (115) in tcp_connect_sockaddr, Failed when trying to open tcp connection - connect() failed [rc = -2] [addr = 162.105.134.222:15003]
Mar 24 10:40:00 pluto PBS_Server[4794]: LOG_ERROR::send_hierarchy, Could not send mom hierarchy to host pluto:15003
Mar 24 10:40:02 pluto PBS_Server[4794]: LOG_ERROR::Operation now in progress (115) in tcp_connect_sockaddr, Failed when trying to open tcp connection - connect() failed [rc = -2] [addr = 202.205.131.254:15003]
```

Comment: indeed, your system runs OutOfMemory (OOM) and the OOM killer got triggered: `samtools invoked oom-killer`. The OOM killer chose `daligner` to be sacrificed/killed to recover some memory for the rest of the system: `Out of memory: Kill process 84352 (daligner) score 36 or sacrifice child`. How much RAM do you have? Did you search what `daligner` and `samtools` processes are on Gentoo.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. My machine's memory is 512G,

Comment: I am majoring in biology. Daligner was used to assembly genome,  there are several daligner thread at the same time that would consume a lot of memory. Previously I think it is the problem of glutster, which was used to linked the other two machine until I look the log of message.

Comment: Do you have swap listed when u run `free -h`? If not, add one or increase it to something larger if you hard drive can handle it.

Comment: I use tmpfs as swap for convenience previously , which I think is stupid at the moment, I should divide a section for swap. Thanks for your suggestion！